# How do I delete a Git branch with TortoiseGit

Tags: git, branch, tortoisegit

Is there an option to delete a branch with [TortoiseGit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseGit)?

I found a [solution for the commandline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-in-github). Is there an implementation in TortoiseGit?

Answer (score 384, accepted):

You should read this article: [Remote branches with TortoiseGit](http://joelabrahamsson.com/entry/remote-branches-with-tortoisegit)

According to this blog post:

...remove the local branch by first opening up the `Checkout/Switch` dialog to get at the `Browse refs` dialog.

[image]

In the `Browse refs` dialog we can right click on the local branch and choose to delete it.

[image]

To delete a remote branch we can do the same thing, but instead of right clicking on our local branch we expand the remotes tree in the left part of the dialog and then locate the remote branch.

[image]

Comment: Btw. please be aware that you cannot delete the branch you are currently on (this will give an error). Also if the branch you want to delete is not visible in the "Browse references" dialog it may have been created recently, do a pull before. And finally there is a direct way to get to "Browse references". See other answer by Razvan Panda.

Comment: @StijndeWitt There is, see [Răzvan Panda's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13327694/321973)

Comment: If you have a lot of old remote branches to clean up, you're probably better off using the command line. I haven't found a way to do this in Tortoise yet. `git remote update origin --prune` will remove any locally saved remote branch refs for branches that no longer exist on `origin`.

Comment: @AdamTuttle It's possible. See way 5 of my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46312594/3247152

Answer (score 111):

You can <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Right Click on the cloned repository and choose `Browse References` from TortoiseGit submenu:

[image]

Click on remotes in the left tree view, and then right click the branch you wish to remove and click on `Delete remote branch`.

[image]

You can also get rid of the "shift"+right click: Go to TortoiseGit settings -> "Set extended context menu" and uncheck "Browse References"

Comment: You can also get rid of the "shift"+right click: Go to TortoiseGit settings -> "Set extended context menu" and uncheck "Browse References"

Comment: Also something really helpful with this solution is you can select multiple branches. Came in handy when having to delete 62 branches. Thanks

Comment: @Noki It's possible to delete branches in Browse references dialog. See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46312594/3247152

Comment: Did this get removed? I don't see any `Set extended context menu`

Answer (score 23):

Open log dialog first, there are ways to delete branch(es):

1. **Right click on branch**
   [image]
2. **Right click on commit**
   [image]
3. In **Browse references** dialog
   [image]
4. **Delete merged branches**
   [image]
5. **Delete those remote-tracking branches** which its remote branches are not exist on remote
   [image]
   [Note] if you want to prune non-exist branches each time you perform fetch, you can do these:
   [image]