# Tortoisegit undo last commit into the repo

Tags: git, github, tortoisegit

Is there an option in tortoisegit to undo the last commit into the repo?

By mistake I pushed a large number of unnecessary files into my git repository(branch:master) which I need to undo. I have searched a lot for the right option in tortoise git to undo the push and go back to the state before the last commit. Please show me a way to undo my last commit.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you need to revert back to the previous state before the last commit just select the commited action from the log list and select `revert changes by this commit`.

Take care, you need to `commit` and `push` again the changes made.

Comment: Thanks for that, it worked fine. But now its giving me another error(A blank alert message with an 'ok' button) when I select the files and click on the commit button. I am using tortoisegit version 1.8.5. But this is not happening for other repository in my PC.

Answer (score 63):

If you haven't pushed your changes yet (so your commit is only local)

1. `TortoiseGit` -> `Show log`
2. Select the commit to which you want to rollback to
3. `Reset "<branch>" to this...`

If you have, then this can still be done, but then you'd have to also do a *force-push* (check "*overwrite known changes*" <sup>1</sup>).

<sup>1</sup> <sub>The "*overwrite known changes*" flag will replace the already pushed commit with a new one. If there is a chance that someone already fetched the commit that you're replacing, don't use this feature, otherwise doing so will create a fork in the history with two conflicting truths.</sub>

---

There is also ***a shortcut*** for when you want to just (1) *redo the last commit* and (2) you *haven't pushed it yet*:

1. Commit -> Check "*Amend Last Commit*"

That will replace the last commit with a new one. But I don't recommend using this - if the last commit is already pushed, you can end up with a big mess. TortoiseGit will *not* stop you here.

By doing a *Reset* you are forced to have a look at the log, and there you see if the commit is local or not.

Comment: I answered my own question. There's no need to remove the non-pointed local commit. Just right click on it and choose 'create branch at this commit' and create a new branch. Then you may follow the link to remove that branch: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705534/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-with-tortoisegit

Comment: @BarryGuvenkaya: I don't think you need to create a new branch. Assuming you haven't pushed, when you reset the existing branch, you'll need to refresh the log and your local commit will disappear since you've reset the index.

Comment: seems that after selecting to Reset (soft) to previous entry at log, you need to press Refresh at TortoiseGit's log to see that item go to the top after the working tree changes and the former top commit disappear