# How can I rename my branch from TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, rename, git-branch, tortoisegit

I know the way to [rename branch from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591213/how-do-i-rename-the-local-branch), but - since I'm using [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/) -  I'm curious if there are any options to do such thing.

Thanks for the answers :)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

In a File Manager, Open your Project root directory (where your `.git` folder is found).

Right click and go to:

```
TortoiseGit > Switch/Checkout
```

Ensure the `Switch To` Option to `Branch`. Then click the little button to the side of the drop down menu that is denoted by `...`

A window will pop up showing the list of branches for you to choose.
Click on the one you want to rename.

Hit <kbd>F2</kbd>.

Rename your branch. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Now in the drop down menu, you'll find that the branch-name has been updated.

Comment: You don't need to use the detour using the switch dialog, you can directly open the browse references dialog, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36134928/3906760

Comment: This does not update remote tracking branches.

Answer (score 21):

If you want to rename a branch which is not the current branch, open the Reference Browser using the context menu of a versioned folder (you might need to hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when opening it).

[image]

select the branch you want to rename and then press <kbd>F2</kbd> (or select rename in the context menu).

[image]

See https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-browse-ref.html

Comment: I think this is much more intuitive and works just fine for current branch too.

Comment: This works great but remember that it doesn't rename your remote branch. Easy way is to just delete the original remote and then push your renamed one. Here's how to delete a remote: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705534/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-with-tortoisegit

Comment: @rusty, no need to delete the branch. Do this instead. 
-> Switch to renamed branch.
-> Right click the repository -> Git commit <renamed branch>
-> Git commit window will open. Write a commit message in the message window, for example: "renaming a branch..."
-> In the bottom left corner, tick the checkbox "Message Only"
-> Commit & Push

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rename just the local branch, you can refer to other answers. Please follow these steps to **rename local and remote** branch.

1. Right click the repository -> TortoiseGit -> Browse References.

[image]

2. Select the branch you want to rename and hit **F2** button and type a new name. The branch is now been renamed locally.

[image]

3. Right click the renamed branch and select "switch/checkout to this.."

[image]

4. Now right click the repository and select "Git Commit -> "renamed branch"

[image]

5. Git commit window will open. Type a commit message and tick the checkbox "Message Only" in the bottom left corner, and then click "Commit & Push"

[image]

Press the upvote button if this answer has helped you.

Comment: I tried this twice. All it does on the remote side is put a commit with a message, no other changes.  Remote Branch name stays the same.

Comment: Don't you see a branch with new name on remote side?

Comment: Nope... old branch name has new message only commit.  No new branch name is found.  I ended up having to do [this](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-rename-local-and-remote-git-branch/) instead.

Comment: The following steps work for me:

    1. Open 'Browse references.'
    2. Delete the remote branch.
    3. Rename the local branch.
    4. Right-click on the local branch and select "Unset tracked branch."
    5. Now, you can publish again.