# How to change terminology from 'master' to 'main' for TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, github, tortoisegit

In keeping with the times, GitHub has changed terminology from `master` to `main`,
but my TortoiseGit still uses `master` as the name of the main branch.

So when I push my local repo to Github, there are now 2 branches in GitHub (`main` and `master`) which causes confusion.

How to make TortoiseGit change to using `main` as the default?

Comment: Side note: *terminology* is the wrong word here. *Terms* might be OK, but it's simpler to just say "change branch names". This also leads you directly to the answer: if you want to change a branch name, ask Git (or TortoiseGit) to change the branch name ([here's how](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36133271/1256452)).

Comment: It's more than just renaming, you also need to change the remote default branch on GitHub.

Comment: Actually GitHub has not changed anything. You are totally free to call the branch master. It will work fine.

Answer (score 6):

This is set in the .gitconfig file You want

```
[init]
    defaultBranch = main
```

Through tortoisegit you would do settings→Git→Edit systemwide gitconfig and change `defaultBranch` from "master" to "main". This requires admin. Alternatively you could edit the global .gitconfig and add the section above.

Answer (score 1):

Branches are just labels for commits (including their history). Also, all branches are basically the same, but we decided ("arbitrarily") that one is the one we do our main work on (this branch could also be named `dev`, `default` or something else).

You have several ways to achieve to have a `main` branch. One is:

1. Create a new local branch `main` that should be your new main branch from now on (you might want to fetch the remote repository before to get the latest changes)
2. Push that branch to GitHub and select "Set upstream/track remote branch" (you might need to push with "force" to hard overwrite the remote branch on GitHub).
3. On GitHub go to the project settings -> Branches and select `main` as your new default branch (can also be done using `git remote set-head origin -a` on the CLI.
4. Delete your local `master` branch and the remote `master` branch on GitHub. (Basically you can also decide to keep your old master branch for some time so that the transition is easier for other people using your repository. Then, however, you need to merge the change of your `main` branch to the old `master` regularly.)

There might be easier ways, but based on your question it is not clear what your current state in the repository currently is.

An alternative could be to switch to a new temporary branch (name doesn't matter, should not be `main`), rename your current local `master` branch to `main` using the Reference Browser, and then proceeding with step 2 (make sure the remote branch is also named `main`). Then, switch to the new `main` branch and finally delete the temporary branch.

---

If you want to have `main` as the default for new repositories, you need to set the Git default using `git config --global init.defaultBranch main` on the CLI (this does not change any exitsing repositories).

Comment: Technically there needs to be a step 0 which would check out `master`, to ensure that `main` created in step 1 points to `master`.

Comment: How to make TortoiseGit change to using main as the default?

Comment: @likejudo Whatv do you mean by "How to make TortoiseGit change to using main as the default?"?

Comment: TortoiseGit uses `master` as the name of its default branch

Comment: @likejudo Are you talking about new repositories or old ones? For old ones, just rename the branch and you're done. Branches are just labels and we decide how we name them. Please be really specific on what you are talking about!

Comment: With a new repository, TortoiseGit uses `master` as the default name. One can select either `main` or `master` as the default name only when TG was **first installed**. After that it uses the initial choice for all repos. It appears that one must uninstall and then reinstall it for it to offer `main` as the default name.

Comment: TortoiseGit does not ask what name should be used as the default. It fully relies on Git, see my answer.

Comment: Not clear, have to search for more detailed information to find where i can change the default branch when creating a new repository

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [@torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek), master is not a special branch. You can just rename it to main by typing the following on git:

`git branch -M <old name> <new name>`

I dont know how to do that in tortoise git. But you should be able to google how to change branch name in tortoise git and follow the instructions