# In TortoiseGit, what is the equivalent of git branch -d (without the --force option)?

Tags: git, branch, tortoisegit

How to delete a Git branch with TortoiseGit has been partially answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9705750/2606569). However it doesn't cover the `--force` option. How can I use TortoiseGit's delete branch feature **without** the `--force` option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TortoiseGit uses `git.exe branch -D` to delete branch if libgit2 is not employed to delete refs. And, there is no use case for `-d` option. See:

[image]

(From TortoiseGit 2.5.2 source code)

However, TortoiseGit usually asks user if they want to delete the branch. See:

[image]

**Useful information**: (from comment by @Fabien Bouleau)

> Git with "-d" checks that the branch has been merged before deleting.
>   TortoiseGit shows an agnostic prompt, a confirmation to prevent a click by mistake.
>   But it does not preserve your work.

**(If you deleted an unmerged branch, you can get it back by using Reflog dialog. Actually, get those commits back. :P )**

Yes. TortoiseGit should do something for deleting unmerged branch.

Comment: Git with "-d" checks that the branch has been merged before deleting. TortoiseGit shows an agnostic prompt, a confirmation to prevent a click by mistake. But it does not preserve your work. Anyway, thanks for the answer! I will submit a request to the TortoiseGit wish list!

Comment: For deleting merged branches, I also provided an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46312594/3247152

Comment: I am adding your comment into my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the "Browse References Dialog" (Context menu: TortoiseGit → Browse Reference..., you might need to hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while opening the context menu) for deleting local branches, TortoiseGit checks whether a specific branch is already merged into `HEAD` and presents a different confirmation dialog.

cf. TortoiseGit manual: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-browse-ref.html

Starting with TortoiseGit 2.5.6 before deletion of a local branch it is checked whether it was merged to HEAD and the result is displayed, so that you can decide whether to delete the branch or not.